# React Javascript JS: Check for empty array entry during map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary, object

I am working on a react js project and need to fill in information inside a table.
I have to extract of calculations and person data into a new object array using map function.
At the end I need an object array like this:

```
const personTableData = {
    key: index,
    personName: Person.Firstname, Person.Lastname,
    personBirthday: Person.Birthday,
    personMaritalStatus: Person.MaritalStatus,
    jobBeforeAccident: calc.BeforeAccJob,
    leadingDiagnosis:
       existing ? (data) : ('No data entry')
    ),
  }));
```

This is my object I use to map:

```
{
    "_id": "611cd9eae20bd167a796f884",
    "BeforeAccJob": "Antennenbauer/-in",
    "FuneralCost": 6,
    "FuneralCostWithSeverancePay": false,
    "FuneralCostSeverancePayDuration": 1,
    "FuneralCostDynamisationRate": 0.025,
    "FuneralCostCapitalisationRate": 0.025,
    "FuneralCostCostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
    },
    "Miscellaneous": 300000.5,
    "MiscellaneousWithSeverancePay": false,
    "MiscellaneousSeverancePayDuration": 1,
    "MiscellaneousCapitalisationRate": 0.025,
    "MiscellaneousDynamisationRate": 0.025,
    "MiscellaneousCostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
    },
    "__typename": "CalculationEntity",
    "Person": {
        "_id": "P30081568",
        "Firstname": "Nick",
        "Lastname": "Fury",
        "Birthday": "1976-10-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "MaritalStatus": "NotSet",
        "Icds": [
            {
                "_id": 610262,
                "Mk": 3,
                "Code": "S12.24",
                "ActineoText": "Fraktur des 6. Halswirbels",
                "Text": "Fraktur des 6. Halswirbels",
                "Status": "unknown",
                "IsLeading": true,
                "__typename": "ProcessICD"
            },
            {
                "_id": 387908,
                "Mk": 4,
                "Code": "S71.88",
                "ActineoText": null,
                "Text": "Weichteilschaden II. Grades bei offener Fraktur oder Luxation der Hüfte und des Oberschenkels",
                "Status": "unknown",
                "IsLeading": true,
                "__typename": "ProcessICD"
            }
        ],
        "__typename": "Person"
    },
    "Blocks": [
        {
            "Name": "PropertyDamageCost",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 1390,
            "WithSeverancePay": false,
            "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "HealingTreatmentCost",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 200,
            "WithSeverancePay": false,
            "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "IncomeCost",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 0,
            "WithSeverancePay": null,
            "SeverancePayDuration": null,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "HousekeepingDamageCost",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 0,
            "WithSeverancePay": false,
            "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "IncreasedNeeds",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 0,
            "WithSeverancePay": false,
            "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "DamageCost",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 0,
            "WithSeverancePay": false,
            "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "SurvivorsPensionCost",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 0,
            "WithSeverancePay": false,
            "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        },
        {
            "Name": "MaintenanceDamageCost",
            "IsRounded": false,
            "Coefficient": 1,
            "Sum": 0,
            "WithSeverancePay": false,
            "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
            "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
            "DynamisationRate": 1,
            "CostSharingAgreement": {
                "Active": false,
                "Rate": 1,
                "Limit": 0,
                "Unlimited": false,
                "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
            },
            "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this attempt, it renders if the data is available, but it is not using my fallback / default value, when I have no data for leading diagnosis. I want to check with another map, during the first map, if I have missing values. Instead of showing 'No data entry' it is displaying me nothing. What did I miss?

```
const personTableData = filteredCalc.map((calc, index) => ({
    key: index,
    personName: `${calc.Person.Firstname} ${calc.Person.Lastname}`,
    personBirthday: <FormattedDate value={calc.Person.Birthday} />,
    personMaritalStatus: calc.Person.MaritalStatus,
    jobBeforeAccident: calc.BeforeAccJob,
    leadingDiagnosis: calc.Person.Icds.map((icd, index) =>
      icd.Code && icd.Text && icd.Mk ? (
        <div key={index}>
          <b style={{ color: '#d9650d' }}>{`${icd.Code}:`}</b> {`${icd.Text}`}
          <div
            style={{
              marginTop: '3px',
              marginBottom: '3px',
            }}
          >
            <b>Schweregrad:</b> {`${icd.Mk}`}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        'No data entry'
      )
    ),
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `filteredCalc` is a Array this works for me so far:

(Note that i used that in javascript only, i don't know where you want to use that)

```js
let personTableData = filteredCalc.map((calc, index) => {
  return {
    key: index,
    personName: `${calc.Person.Firstname} ${calc.Person.Lastname}`,
    personBirthday: `${calc.Person.Birthday}`,
    personMaritalStatus: calc.Person.MaritalStatus,
    jobBeforeAccident: calc.BeforeAccJob,
    leadingDiagnosis: calc.Person.Icds.map((icd, index2) => {
      if (icd.Code && icd.Text && icd.Mk) {
        return `<div key=${index}>
                    <b style="color:#d9650d">${icd.Code}:</b>${icd.Text}
                    <div style="marginTop:3px;marginBottom:3px;">
                        <b>Schweregrad:</b>${icd.Mk}
                    </div>
                </div>`
      } else {
        return "no entry";
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Example with your data (no HTML):

```js
let filteredCalc = [{
  "_id": "611cd9eae20bd167a796f884",
  "BeforeAccJob": "Antennenbauer/-in",
  "FuneralCost": 6,
  "FuneralCostWithSeverancePay": false,
  "FuneralCostSeverancePayDuration": 1,
  "FuneralCostDynamisationRate": 0.025,
  "FuneralCostCapitalisationRate": 0.025,
  "FuneralCostCostSharingAgreement": {
    "Active": false,
    "Rate": 1,
    "Limit": 0,
    "Unlimited": false,
    "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
  },
  "Miscellaneous": 300000.5,
  "MiscellaneousWithSeverancePay": false,
  "MiscellaneousSeverancePayDuration": 1,
  "MiscellaneousCapitalisationRate": 0.025,
  "MiscellaneousDynamisationRate": 0.025,
  "MiscellaneousCostSharingAgreement": {
    "Active": false,
    "Rate": 1,
    "Limit": 0,
    "Unlimited": false,
    "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
  },
  "__typename": "CalculationEntity",
  "Person": {
    "_id": "P30081568",
    "Firstname": "Nick",
    "Lastname": "Fury",
    "Birthday": "1976-10-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "MaritalStatus": "NotSet",
    "Icds": [{
        "_id": 610262,
        "Mk": 3,
        "Code": "S12.24",
        "ActineoText": "Fraktur des 6. Halswirbels",
        "Text": "Fraktur des 6. Halswirbels",
        "Status": "unknown",
        "IsLeading": true,
        "__typename": "ProcessICD"
      },
      {
        "_id": 387908,
        "Mk": 4,
        "Code": "S71.88",
        "ActineoText": null,
        "Text": "Weichteilschaden II. Grades bei offener Fraktur oder Luxation der Hüfte und des Oberschenkels",
        "Status": "unknown",
        "IsLeading": true,
        "__typename": "ProcessICD"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Person"
  },
  "Blocks": [{
      "Name": "PropertyDamageCost",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 1390,
      "WithSeverancePay": false,
      "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    },
    {
      "Name": "HealingTreatmentCost",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 200,
      "WithSeverancePay": false,
      "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    },
    {
      "Name": "IncomeCost",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 0,
      "WithSeverancePay": null,
      "SeverancePayDuration": null,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    },
    {
      "Name": "HousekeepingDamageCost",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 0,
      "WithSeverancePay": false,
      "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    },
    {
      "Name": "IncreasedNeeds",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 0,
      "WithSeverancePay": false,
      "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    },
    {
      "Name": "DamageCost",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 0,
      "WithSeverancePay": false,
      "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    },
    {
      "Name": "SurvivorsPensionCost",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 0,
      "WithSeverancePay": false,
      "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    },
    {
      "Name": "MaintenanceDamageCost",
      "IsRounded": false,
      "Coefficient": 1,
      "Sum": 0,
      "WithSeverancePay": false,
      "SeverancePayDuration": 1,
      "CapitalisationRate": 0.025,
      "DynamisationRate": 1,
      "CostSharingAgreement": {
        "Active": false,
        "Rate": 1,
        "Limit": 0,
        "Unlimited": false,
        "__typename": "CostSharingAgreement"
      },
      "__typename": "CalculationBlock"
    }
  ]
}];

let personTableData = filteredCalc.map((calc, index) => {
  return {
    key: index,
    personName: `${calc.Person.Firstname} ${calc.Person.Lastname}`,
    personBirthday: `${calc.Person.Birthday}`,
    personMaritalStatus: calc.Person.MaritalStatus,
    jobBeforeAccident: calc.BeforeAccJob,
    leadingDiagnosis: calc.Person.Icds.map((icd, index2) => {
      if (icd.Code && icd.Text && icd.Mk) {
        return `<div key=${index}>
                    <b style="color:#d9650d">${icd.Code}:</b>${icd.Text}
                    <div style="marginTop:3px;marginBottom:3px;">
                        <b>Schweregrad:</b>${icd.Mk}
                    </div>
                </div>`
      } else {
        return "no entry";
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(personTableData)
```